# SimpleHtmlDOM, PHP, Fatal Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs

Tags: php, error-handling, web-crawler, simple-html-dom, information-retrieval

I am trying to build this script that gets news from a certain news portal. This should output the News number, News Title, Image, Source URL, and the news content. It is supposed to fetch 50 articles, however at a random number it will stop fetching and throw a fatal error, stating that basically find() is calling an empty non existent object.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\test2.php on line 7
```

I just don't understand why it would never fetch all the news, instead it fetches random number of news until the error happens.Randomly, sometimes it works and shows all 50 news articles.

The problem seems to occur on this line:

```
$article = file_get_html($link);

foreach($article->find('div.article') as $content){
```

However below is the full script. Let me know if you need to clarify anything more, suggestions are appreciated.

```
$t=0;
$page = file_get_html('http://www.website.com/?');
foreach($page->find('div[class="news-other-box"] h3 a') as $crawl){
    $title = $crawl->plaintext; //gets article title
    $link = $crawl->href; //gets article link
    $article = file_get_html($link);  //fetching article page   
    foreach($article->find('div.article') as $content){
            $content=$content->plaintext;//fetching content of article
            foreach($article->find('img[itemprop]') as $img1){  
                $img=$img1->src;  
                $img=saveIMG($img,'news_images');  //save img function, and returns image path "images/source/image_name.jpg" 
            }
            echo "<b>" . $t . "</b>\n ";
            echo $title  . "<br>\n";
            echo '<img src="'.$img.'" /> ' . "<br>\n";
            echo $link . "<br>\n" ; 
            echo $content . "<br><br>\n";
            $t++;
        }       
    }
```

Comment: The error means that `file_get_html()` is failing -- it returns `false` when this happens. This could be because the URL is wrong, the HTML is invalid, or the response is too big.

Comment: The maximum size it will process is `600KB`. You can edit the `define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 600000);` line to increase this.

Comment: i believe the response is too big, are you able to change the size of the response?

Comment: @Barmar I will try that and let you know, thank you.

Comment: also see the linked duplicate question, in it's comment it has other library recommendations that should be superior to simple html dom.

Comment: **THANK YOU** i just edited the  max_file_size on simple_html_dom.php and it did the job.